# Is the screen dry or wet?

Tags: iphone, screen, damage

I got caught in the rain yesterday, my iPhone 5 was in my pocket. Some water got into it. Here`s the picture, moisture is under screen surface:

[image]

Question is: **which area is dry and which is wet**? Dark one or light one?
I am asking, because the next day dark area increased in size to whole screen size. And now whole screen is dark. I wonder, is now my whole screen dry or is it wet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've once got water in a Dell (work)laptop and it started to get lighter and lighter the further water got. This is because the screen is built with multiple layers and you got water between them.

[image]

I would definately recommend you to shut down the device and [put it in rice.](http://www.macworld.co.uk/news/apple/iphone-water-damage-rescue-soaked-device-rice-trick-3455144/)

Comment: Well, that's the free way to increase you screen brightness, itn't it? No battery overload, right? If we could get some watery liquid which doesn't evaporate, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think Silica gel would work also and could absorb moisture a bit faster I am not so sure because I haven't tried it yet.